# Java. Which class do I use to create GUI?

Tags: java, oop

Last semester I coded classes for a doctors office. I have 4 classes created and working. They are Patients, Procdures, Payments and then MainSystem. I now want to design a GUI for the system. I know how to code frame, buttons etc.. and have it done in my notepad but I don't know where to put the code for the GUI. Do I create a new class or do I put the code into one of the existing classes?

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a new class. The Patients, Procdures, Payments and then MainSystem classes are all part of your **Model**, and so you will want to now create a **View** class (likely classes) to display the state of your model. You want your model code to be as view- or gui- agnostic as possible. In other words, the model classes should not care and should still work if they are being displayed in a Swing GUI, an SWT GUI, in a console program or in an Android program.

Check out some [Java MVC tutorials](https://www.google.com/?q=mvc+tutorial+java&gws_rd=ssl#q=mvc+tutorial+java) such as [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm) for more at what I'm driving at. Also for a search on this site, please check out [these links](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+mvc).

Comment: OK Thanks. I'm getting downvotes on this question and I don't know why. I started programming 16 weeks ago after years as a geography teacher so I know I'm probably asking stupid questions. Apologies.

Comment: @SSI: Your question is a bit broad. Don't let the down-votes get you down, but don't ignore them either and do read the [help] and [tour] sites since if you ask too many questions with down-votes, including deleted questions, it could prevent you from asking further questions.